# Django email log file "sent" growing

Tags: django, django-email, django-logging

I have a `sent` file that keeps growing on my staging server. It stores a log of all emails sent and I don't know what's causing this behaviour, it doesn't look like a feature from the Django framework (1.8).

I can't find any reference of this log file in the source code. It's an issue for several reasons, including the fact that it causes the server to run out of disk space.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious in the Django config. I don't see how to fix this issue besides running a cron task to delete that file regularly. I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: What email backend are you using? Any custom libraries that manage you mail sending process? Are emails being delivered correctly or are there errors?

Comment: I use `from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives` which seems to be a core plugin, emails are sent correctly. I'm not aware of any custom library to manage the emails. I basically define `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` and other constants in my `settings.py`.

Comment: Whats the path to the `sent` log file (is it inside your django app)? Do you know if Django intself is writting that file or some other process?

Comment: Have you configured any loggers in `settings.py LOGGING` that would write such a file?

Comment: The path is outside of the Django project, basically in its parent folder. And there aren't any `LOGGING` stuff. I've also checked all imports of `import logging` in the code and couldn't find anything relevant. I checked the crons as well and nothing relevant there either. I've asked my host provider if it's a feature from them and it's not. @Ralf Thanks for the hints anyway!